Quand est-ce qu'on exprime l'age de quelque chose par an vs année?
J'ai vu cette phrase dans un livre plus tôt:

-- Ces vêtements doivent avoir des dizaines d'années ! remarqua Michael.

Mais je sais qu'on dit e.g. "J'ai dix ans", et pas "j'ai dix années."
Quelle est la différence?

"J'ai vu cette phrase dans un livre récemment." // En français, du moins de nos jours, de façon consistante la ponctuation de phrase se place hors des guillemets : « J'ai dix ans", et pas "j'ai dix années". ».

You will glean much precise information here (an), and here (année), although more details could be added for a better understanding.

Une explication plus concise et claire pour les différences d'emplois ici.

@None thank you I do know the difference in general and I had already seen the question you linked, I was more just surprised by this specific instance because I had never seen avoir années specifically rather than avoir ans in reference to age.

The link you gave is a helpful refresher all the same. Btw @LPH I I do know to use guillemets but sometimes I am on a device where it is too much trouble to find those characters.

@temporary_user_name Ce n'est pas ce que je voulais dire; le fait que les gens n'utilisent pas les guillemets français est accepté en raison de la difficulté dans la frappe ; sur ma machine, et partout ailleurs, je pense, le guillemet gauche est  « Alt + 0171 » et le droit est « Alt + 0187 » (chiffres sur clavier numérique, évidemment) mais on tolère que les guillemets anglais soient utilisés à la place des français parce qu'ils évitent aux gens le « typing hassle ». Vous pouvez continuer à utiliser le guillemet anglais, presque tout le monde le fait.  (1/2)

@temporary_user_name Non, ce n'est pas ça. Il s'agit de la place du second guillemet à la fin des phrases : si on cite par exemple le bout de phrase « J'ai dix années » à la fin d'une phrase, en AmE on a « "j'ai dix années." » ou « "j'ai dix années;" » ou « "j'ai dix années!" » ; en français (moderne) on a « "j'ai dix années". », « "j'ai dix années" ; » et  « "j'ai dix années" ! »  (en remplaçant les guillemets pour faciliter la frappe). (2/2)

OH pardon j'ai mal compris ta première commentaire; je comprends maintenant. Merci. J'ai mal lu gravement.

Dans cette phrase l'emploi du mot années est lié à celui de dizaines.
L'âge exact s'exprime normalement à l'aide d'un adjectif numéral (un, deux, dix, vingt-cinq, etc...)

Ce pull a dix ans. (On est en 2024 et je me souviens que je l'ai acheté en 2014).

Le nom dizaine n'est pas synonyme de dix. Une dizaine c'est un ensemble de dix dans un contexte mathématique.  Une dizaine d'années exprime une période de dix ans (voir cette réponse), c'est le temps écoulé entre deux dates, d'où l'emploi de année et pas de an. Hors du contexte mathématique dizaine veut dire environ dix. Employer une dizaine pour exprimer un âge signifie qu'on ne connait pas l'âge exact, une dizaine d'années signifie à peu près dix ans.

« Il a une dizaine d'années » veut dire « il a environ dix ans ».

Dizaines étant au pluriel dans l'exemple de la question, indique bien que ça n'exprime pas un âge. Des dizaines ça veut dire « vraiment beaucoup », sous-entendu : « il est très vieux ce pull »¹.

¹ En anglais je traduirais par It's decades old qui fait écho à "dix", ages old ou, comme suggéré par @jlliagre, dozens of years old. 

Omg I'm very glad I asked this, parce qu'en fait je ne m'étais pas rendu compte que dizaine en français n'est pas dozen en anglais. C'est comme un faux ami! Le mot en français est douzaine, et je ne le savais pas jusqu'à maintenant.

@temporary_user_name Pas vraiment, sauf si je ne te comprends pas. C'est juste que en français  pour dire « un grand nombre de quelque chose »  en français on se réfère à 10 (des dizaines de ...) et en anglais à douze (dozens of...).  Et dizaine (au singulier) a un sens que n'a pas dozen en anglais (environ 10) dozen, au singulier, c'est toujours 12 quelque chose.

Oui, c'est ce que je veux dire - une dizaine ne signifie pas 12. Je ne savais pas le mot douzaine jusqu'à maintenant.
